# What should the value be of a Kinesis Partition key

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

So, I thought this would be easy to answer, but my google skills are coming up dry.

I have a flink producer that is currently setting the default Paritition to "0".  Now that I want to handle more than one shard, I need to change that up, but I can't find a good description of what a good partitionKey should be.  Looking in our code base, some just pass the current epoch seconds.  Others take the first 100 characters of the stream they are reading.

What is Kinesis expecting for a value?  What happens if I send a value that doesn't match a shard?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partition key should be a value that gives you the best possible even distribution. It's used to distribute the data across different shards and you would like to end up with a situation where the data is evenly distributed across the different shards. It depends on your incoming data, but you can think of values like a customer ID or a transaction ID.

Comment: so if I have 10 shards, can i just use 1 thru 10?  What happens if I used 1-25 and only have 10 shards, does it handle for that in the calculation? Can i just feed it any data, and as long as its different enough, they will land on different shards?  My big problem is I can find actual example data examples, just highly abstracted statements.

Comment: I don't think you should be looking at the number of shards, but at your incoming data what provides the most even distribution. Let's say you use `customer` of which you have a maximum of 10 customers and 10 shards, every shard would get the data for 1 customer. If you grow to 25 customers, there will be 5 shards that get the data of 3 customers and 5 shards that get the data of 2 customers. It's still a pretty even distribution across the shards.